# Differential of an inverse function - do we need continuity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The theorem about the derivative of the inverse function says that if

- $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x_0) \neq 0$
- $f$ has an inverse function
- $f^{-1}$ is continuous in $f(x_0)$
  then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable in $y = f(x_0)$

Do we need the assumption about the continuity of the inverse function?

Comment: Please state all assumptions. This is obviously wrong for $f(x) = x^3$ at $x=0$.

Comment: these are not very well stated assumptions

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to mention that $f'(x_0)$ must be non singular. With this assumption, and the mild extra assumption of continuity of $f'$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$, the inverse function theorem kicks in and automatically ensures continuity and differentiability of the inverse function. (This is true even in the general context of Banach spaces).

> This leaves open the existence of a differentiable functions $f$ with non-continuous derivative $f'$, with the property that $f'(x_0)$ is nonsingular and the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $f(x_0)$.

I am not sure you can find such examples in finite dimension. In infinite dimension, however, those abound: consider for instance the injection $I\colon \ell^1\to \ell^2$, which is linear and continuous, hence differentiable with nonsingular differential. The inverse function $I^{-1}\colon I(\ell^1) \to \ell^1$ is not continuous.

(I had written some personal notes about this topic [here](https://negropeppe.wordpress.com/2015/12/10/the-inverse-function-theorem/). Those are meant for my personal record, but perhaps they can be of some help. Lemma 1 is the reason why I suspect one cannot find examples of functions with discontinuous inverse in finite dimension.)

Comment: What is $\ell^1$?

Comment: @marmistrz: It is the space $$\ell^1=\left\{(x_1, x_2, \ldots )\ :\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|<\infty\right\}, $$ 
with norm 
$$\|x\|_{\ell^1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|.$$

Comment: f' only needs to be continuous and nonsingular at x_0 for there to exist a differentiable local inverse to f, even in general Banach space case.

Comment: @FShrike: but this contradicts the example I wrote. Is that wrong?

Comment: @AShrike: sorry about the delay, I am having a little time off, holidays. So, I respectfully disagree with all you say. First, $\ell^1$ does inject into $\ell^2$ as the following inequality shows: $$\sum \lvert x_j\rvert^2 \le (\sum \lvert x_j\rvert)^2.$$The proof is easy, just expand the right-hand side and you immediately see it.  This injection is the content of my counterexample to your claim about the existence of differentiable local inverses.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It seems I've become confused with $L_1\subseteq L_2$ (which is false in general) and $\ell_1\subseteq\ell_2$ which is true here

Comment: My previous comment was also poorly phrased. In general, $\mathrm{d}f$ only needs to be continuous and nonsingular at $x_0$ to guarantee a local inverse to $f$ which is differentiable **at $x_0$**; this local inverse need not be continuous or differentiable anywhere else

Comment: And it's false that in your case $\mathrm{d}I(x_0)=I:\ell_1\to\ell_2$ is nonsingular; it cannot be invertible because it is not surjective. Maybe "nonsingular" is weird terminology here; I mean for $\mathrm{d}f(x_0)$ to be invertible

Comment: @AShrike: Now I agree. Clearly $df$ is not invertible, even though it is injective. So it seems that my "counterexample" is rooted in subtleties in terminology, rather than in some deep mathematical phenomenon. Thanks!